# Setting control height explicitly

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a XamDataGrid in one of my user controls, inside of a stackpanel.  I want the grid to maintain the same height regardless of how many rows are present in the grid.  To do that, I set the grid's Height property to an explicit value.

Is that how things are done in WPF?  Every time I do explicit sizing I feel like I am doing WinForms and not using WPF properly.  Is setting the Height directly the only/correct solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with setting an explicit Height in situations where you want an element to always stay the same height. Where it's less appropriate is in situations where sizing is better handled by the parent layout Panel or the element's child content which can use the available space dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

WPF uses a relative measurement system which at first glance is not intuitive. I have never found an example when I was forced to use explicit sizes ( once when I paint something on Canvas). I use styles in 90% cases where I define Padding, Margin, Aligment etc. Sometimes I use MinHeight and MinWidth for simple things.

About that Grid you can put it in the ScrollViewer or ViewBox to have dynamic sizing, yet If it won't be trouble set the explicit Height.